# Ошибка доступа к памяти в методе класса

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Беда следующая: работаю со списком в классе(Использование STL запрещено) худо бедно расписал методы. Далее когда описываю экземпляр в main и пытаюсь вызвать метод addElement возникает ошибка доступа к памяти. Как быть? Из-за чего так происходит?

Листинг main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "vset.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vset a;
    a.AddElement(&a.ilast, 5);
    //  a.AddElement(&a.last, 7);
    a.PrintList(a.ihead);
    return 0;
}
```

Листинг реализации класса vset.cpp

```
    #pragma once
    #include "vset.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    vset::SingleList * vset::makeFirst(int d)
    {
        SingleList *cRec = new SingleList;
        cRec->Data = d; cRec->next = 0; cRec->prev = 0;
        return cRec;
    }

    void vset::AddElement(vset::SingleList **last, int d)
    {
        vset::SingleList *cRec = new SingleList;
        cRec->Data = d; cRec->next = 0; cRec->prev = *last;
        (*last)->next = cRec;
        *last = cRec;
    }

    vset::SingleList * vset::search(SingleList * const pbeg, int d)
    {
        SingleList *cRec = pbeg;
        while (cRec)
        {
            if (cRec->Data == d)break;
            cRec = cRec->next;
        }
        return cRec;
    }

    bool vset::remove(vset::SingleList **head, vset::SingleList **last, int key)
    {
        if (SingleList *pkey = search(*head, key))
        {
            if (pkey == *head)
            {
                *head = (*head)->next;
                (*head)->prev = 0;
            }
            else if (pkey == *last)
            {
                *last = (*last)->prev;
                (*last)->next = 0;
            }
            else {
                (pkey->prev)->next = pkey->next;
                (pkey->next)->prev = pkey->prev;
            }
            delete pkey;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    vset::SingleList * vset::insert(vset::SingleList * const head, vset::SingleList **last, int key, int d)
    {
        if (SingleList *pkey = search(head, key))
        {
            SingleList *cRec = new SingleList;
            cRec->Data = d; cRec->next = pkey->next;
            cRec->prev = pkey; pkey->next = cRec;
            if (pkey != *last) (cRec->next)->prev = cRec;
            else *last = cRec;
            return cRec;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void vset::PrintList(vset::SingleList * const head)
    {
        SingleList *cRec = head;
        while (cRec)
        {
            cout << cRec->Data << " ";

            cRec = cRec->next;
        }
    }

    void getData()
    {

    }

    vset::vset()
    {
        SingleList *ihead = makeFirst(0);
        SingleList *ilast = ihead;
    //  getLast(&last);
    }

    vset::vset(int d)
    {
        SingleList *ihead = makeFirst(d);
        SingleList *ilast = ihead;
    }
    /*vset::SingleList getLast(vset::SingleList **last)
    {
        static vset::SingleList **olast;
        if (!last) olast = last;
        return **olast;
    }*/
    vset::~vset()
    {
    }
```

Интерфейс vset.h

```
    #pragma once

    class vset
    {
    public:
        struct SingleList
        {
            int Data;

            SingleList *next;
            SingleList *prev;
        };
        SingleList *ihead;
        SingleList *ilast;
    public:
        vset();
        vset::vset(int d);
        ~vset();
        SingleList * makeFirst(int d);
        void AddElement(SingleList **last, int d);
        SingleList * search(SingleList * const pbeg, int d);
        bool remove(SingleList **head, SingleList **last, int key);
        SingleList * insert(SingleList * const head, SingleList **last, int key, int d);
        void PrintList(SingleList * const head);
        void getData();
        vset::SingleList getLast(vset::SingleList);
    };
```

Comment: `vset::vset(int d);` - в определении класса такой синтаксис не допускается. С чего это вдруг у вас именно для этого конструктора вдруг стало `vset::vset(int d);`?

Comment: пробовал. ошибка возникает на строке (*last)->next = cRec; Причём данная программа вне класса работает нормально

Comment: Обратите внимание на изменение значения переменных и полей класса.

Comment: Плюс ко всему не нужно писать лишнее  - например: void vset::AddElement(vset::SingleList **last, int d)... Вы уже указали область видимости, и в аргументе просто нужен  SingleList ** last, - незачем второй раз указывать, что тип из vset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем исправление ошибок:)

- `#pragma once` в cpp классе? серьезно?
- `vset::vset(int d);` - вот так в объявлении класса не нужно писать. Правильно писать вот так `vset(int d);`или ещё лучше так `explicit vset(int d);`
- Ошибки в конструкторе-деструкторе

  ```
  vset::vset()
  {
      SingleList *ihead = makeFirst(0);
      SingleList *ilast = ihead;
  //  getLast(&last);
  }
  ```

Здесь объявлены указатели, имя которых пересекается с переменными класса. По выходу с конструктора эти указатели потеряются, а значение переменных класса так и останется неинициализированным. Правильно конструктор писать где то так

```
    vset::vset()
    {
        ihead = makeFirst(0);
        ilast = ihead;
    }
```

После этого код как минимум уже запускается и работает как нужно.

Но в нем есть ещё утечка - в деструкторе не освобождается память. По хорошему можно написать функцию clear, которая будет очищать содержимое и просто вызывать ее в деструкторе.

Но есть ещё пару замечаний. Функция AddElement требует указателя на последний элемент. Если ей передать просто указатель на произвольный элемент, то она испортит список. (будет как бы вилка). Поэтому, лучше этот параметр оттудова совсем убрать.

Также функции у Вас названы в разнобой. Есть и маленькими буквами, и CamelCase, и camelCase. Приведите все к одному виду.

Comment: Касательно форматирования я пока не заморачиваюсь. Научиться бы программировать нормально сначала. По факту я сначала пишу код, а потом его привожу в удобочитаемый вид. Замечание учту)

Comment: распространенное заблуждение. Код потом превращается в кашу и разбираться  с ним на порядок сложнее.

Comment: хорошо. Касательно vset::vset(int d) IntelliSense без vset:: или с explicit начинает сильно ругаться и говорит что требуется индентификатор, а explicit вообще недопустим. Если помнить слова нашего препода, то в хедере не есть хорошо писать реализацию состоящую больше чем из 1 строки кода...(хотя тут можно сделать так чтоб по фен шую, но тем не менее)

Comment: я надеюсь  vset::vset(int d) в хедере исправляете? а не cpp файле,  где все написано в этом месте правильно

Comment: теперь в хедере =D

Comment: С чего Вы взяли, что у него прагма в классе? Она у него вообще в другом файле. Может он его куда-то желает по #include подставить?

Comment: врядли он желает вставлять cpp файл в какой то другой. Да, так можно сделать, но не нужно.

Comment: А вот интересно, кто решил минус поставить?